# use drop down to specify workbook for formula reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula in excel as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('[XXXXX.xlsx]01 04 2014'!$E$2:$E$922=C$7)+0)
```

I also have a data validation drop down in cell B2 that lists multiple client names.

What I'd like todo is be able to use the drop down in B2 to allow me to change the workbook being referenced in the above formula.

Something such as:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('[$B$2.xlsx]01 04 2014'!$E$2:$E$922=C$7)+0)
```

^^ This obviously doesn't work, however I hope it gives an idea what I'm trying to achieve. Ideally I'd also like to use another cell to specify the `01 04 2014` reference.

Essentially I'm trying to create something like;

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('[$B$2.xlsx]$C$3'!$E$2:$E$922=C$7)+0)
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the drop down via the DATA VALIDATION feature? It sounds like you're using an auto-generated drop down list.

To create a validated list you need to list the items in a place out of the way that wont be deleted. Let's say its Sheet2!a1:a5. Now on click on sheet1!b2 (which is your drop down menu cell.) and go to Data Tab->Data Validation->Under Allow select List; Under Source put Sheet2!a1:a5

Any formula referencing Sheet1!b2 should accept the current drop down item as the "current cell" and should update when you change your selection in b2. I tried this just now on my excel2010 and it works.

Comment: The DATA VALIDATION is referencing a list on a validation page, it does work correctly, however I am struggling to have this work as part of my formula.

Comment: Can you specify what data type is in the box? Can you copy the exact formula? What is the formula actually suppose to achieve? If you're sure you're using the a proper drop down box, then it is a syntax error. Without knowing what you want the formula to do, we wont be able to correct that part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue as follows;

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("'["&$B$5&".xlsx]"&VALIDATION!$G7&"'!$E$2:$E$2000")=C$7)+0)
```

With B5 being the cell containing the dropdown and also VALIDATION!$G7 being the cell containing the workbook sheet name.